# Iterate a large matrix calculation

Tags: assignment, infinite-loop

I want to repeat the calculation of a pretty big formula about 100 times.
I tried using Do loop but it takes sooo much time that mathematica stops working.
I will take a simple example to illustrate what I want to do because my formula and the vectors/matrix that I use are quite horrible
 I don't know how to formulate that with a for loop because it doesn't depend of an increment

```
M={{1,3},{5,9},{2,1}};
a={3,5,7};
x={1,1,1};``
Do[xb=x-(M[[1]]/(M[[1]].M[[1]])); x=xb,{100}] xb
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably you should use `Nest[ ]`,but it won't speed up the calc too much. Difficult to say without timing the steps.

Comment: Anyway, in your example you could pre-calculate `(M[[1]]/(M[[1]].M[[1]])`

Comment: Why do you even include `a`?  Moreover, your dimension of `x` is not the same as `M[[1]]` so your code cannot work.

Answer (score 2):

First, do not use upper-case letters to start names of functions or variables, as they may conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal names.

Second, the dimensionality of `x` and of `m` should be the same (if you wish to subtract one from the other), but yours are not the same.  I assumed that you simply have the reversed dimensions of `m`, and so took its transpose.

Then I deleted the useless `a`.

Then I computed the constant array (and called it `zz`).

```
m = {{1, 3}, {5, 9}, {2, 1}};
x = {1, 1, 1};
zz = (Transpose[m][[1]]/(Transpose[m][[1]].Transpose[m][[1]]));
```

Then I used `Nest` to iterate the computation 100 times, as shown:

```
Nest[# - zz &, x, 100]
```

(* 
{-(7/3), -(47/3), -(17/3)}
*)

This simple computation was *extremely* fast (0.000609 seconds).

Comment: @DavidGStork, don't you think that `x - 100 zz` would give the same result?

Comment: Would not `zz=With[{tm = Transpose[m][[1]]}, (tm/(tm.tm))]` be better?

Comment: Ever so slightly.

Comment: garej:  Your solution might work for a purely linear function, but won't in general.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, could you clarify? I did not mean to provide a solution. I'm just not sure that the problem itself stated correctly. So, how can it be nonlinear?

Comment: If the update rule is simply subtracting a fixed vector from the initial vector, then of course you can skip the iterations and merely subtract $n$ times the update vector.  If instead the update rule is *non* linear, then garej's linear solution simply will not work.